# Meaning of [^K]+name\?=([^']*) in Plain and Simple English

Tags: regex

Can someone please dumb this expression down for me and provide a meaning of this expression COMBINED... I think I know what each char means, but what it returns (as a full expression) is what I'd like to understand  in plain simple English :)

**[^K]+name\?=([^']*)**

Thanks

EDIT: Please SEE picture: [image: http://i.imgur.com/0bDhJmp.png]

Why it's returning the 2nd instance of "name" (peterandjohn) and not the 1st one "Mark=Scoobidooo"?!!

THX

EDIT2:

[image]

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/#%5B%5EK%5D%2Bname%5C%3F%3D(%5B%5E'%5D*)

Comment: How is that helpful? The link lacks the closing paren and just produces an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the '+' quantifier is "greedy" - it tries to match as much as it possibly can (even if it has already found a match) before the next part of the regex can be matched.

In layman terms, `[^K]+` will not just stop matching at

"**output:'**name?=Mark=scobidoo'", because the "**name?=Mark**..."

following it *is also matched* by [^K]+ (remember that you've made your regex *case-sensitive*, which is why the 'k' in Mark matches `[^K]+`). The `[^K]+` will finally stop matching at "**output:'**name?=peteandjohn'`", since that is the last position after which we can still match the rest of the regex, i.e. "name\?=([^']*)".

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you divesh.. Exactly what I was looking for. Cheers! Now here is another twist, if I want to make sure only the 2nd one is returned "peteandjohn", then what will the regex look like, in the example code above? thanks again...

Comment: Isn't the current regular expression returning the second name? Or did you mean you want the first name to be returned?

Comment: You're correct, but lets' say that for the sake of argument the K in MarK is capital, AND that the ALL the code preceding name?= is identical in both instances (appearances) of "name?=" Is there a slick way to return the peteandjohn? (see example above under edit2)

Comment: Which tool are you using to parse the regex?

Comment: I think it's Python. But what I know is I cannot use multiple lines of code or script. I just need an expression like [^K]+name\?=([^']*) Thx

Comment: Sorry, never worked on Python before. Maybe create a separate question for this? You might want to checkout http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48194/discussion-between-divesh-premdeep-and-user2957951)

Answer (score 4):

Regex : `[^K]+name\?=([^']*)`

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^K]+                    any character except: 'K' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  name                     'name'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \?                       '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: Thanks. As I've mentioned I know what each char means, BUT the combined expression is what I'm struggling to understand :( Maybe an example would help :) Cheers!